# Grails - Event Push doesn't send event to the client

Tags: grails, plugins, websocket, push-notification, atmosphere

I'm trying to use Event Push plugin and I have not managed to make it work. I read several subjects without success.

When I call `newActivities`, I get an error in the Chrome console:
`SSE failed. Downgrading to fallback transport and resending`

I don't know if it's an set up or version plugin/dependencies issue

**BuildConfig**

```
dependencies {
  compile 'org.atmosphere:atmosphere-runtime:2.1.4'
}

plugins {

  compile(":events-push:1.0.M7") {
            excludes 'resources'
            excludes 'atmosphere-runtime'
        }
}
```

**MyEvents.groovy in conf directory**

```
events = {
    'UserNotification' namespace: 'browser', browser:true
}
```

**TestController**

```
def newEvent() {
    event([namespace: 'browser', topic: 'UserNotification'])
    render "OK"
}
```

**myView.gsp**

```
<r:require module="grailsEvents"/>
<r:script>
   var grailsEvents = new grails.Events("../TestController/newEvent",{transport:'sse'});         
   grailsEvents.on("UserNotification",function(){ alert("OK");});
</r:script>
```

Comment: what is your Grails version? Check this out: https://github.com/smaldini/grails-events-push/issues/61

Comment: I'm using Grails 2.0.3